# ¿Por qué se usa el subjuntivo en "quien fuera uno de los fundadores"?

Tags: subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

La portada del libro *Guerra de Yugurta* (ISBN 968366153X) tiene esta frase:

> La Biblioteca Sciptorvm Graecorvm et Romanorvm edita por segunda ocasión la *Guerra de Yugurta*, los *Fragmentos de las historias* y las *Cartas a César sobre el gobierno de la república*, del temperamento Cayo Salustio Crispo, en versión hecha en español por Augustín Millares Carlo, quien **fuera** uno de los fundadores de esta colección hace ya más de cincuenta años.

¿Por qué se usa "fuera" en vez de "fue"?

Answer (score 11):

El uso del subjuntivo con valor de indicativo es bastante común en el periodismo, aunque se considera incorrecto y la mayoría de los manuales de estilo lo desaconsejan.

> Por último, el que más espacio dedica a la advertencia sobre ese mal
>   uso es nuestro Manual de Español Urgente: "No debe aparecer en los
>   despachos de la agencia la forma cantara como equivalente de había
>   cantado o de cantó. ("La sesión, que comenzara a las cuatro de la
>   tarde, se prolongó hasta la madrugada".) Se trata de una pedantería
>   ajena al buen empleo del español moderno (o de un influjo gallego o
>   asturiano). Cantara tuvo ese valor de pluscuamperfecto de indicativo,
>   heredado del latín en la Edad Media, pero lo fue perdiendo, y
>   adquiriendo el de imperfecto de subjuntivo hasta que confundió sus
>   usos con los de cantase. Fueron los poetas románticos quines, para
>   "medievalizar" su estilo, resucitaron el antiguo valor ya olvidado de
>   cantara, y desde entonces se ha mantenido en la literatura. Pero debe
>   estar ausente del lenguaje periodístico, donde ha penetrado por las
>   citadas causas".

http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Imperfecto%20subjuntivo%20literario.htm

Comment: Interesante, gracias.  Entonces podemos reemplazar "fuera" con "había sido".  Y supongo que nunca (¿o muy infrecuentemente?) veremos una frase semejante pero con "fuese".

Comment: Y pensándolo más, me parece que podríamos decir que este uso del subjuntivo está fuera de lugar en el periodismo y más generalmente en los textos dirigidos a las masas, pero en una colección de textos grecolatinos no hay ningún problema en usar este arcaísmo.

Comment: @MichaelWolf: Yo no lo usaría en ningún tipo de texto, un texto científico no ha de ser pedante ni ha de alejarse necesariamente del lenguaje de "las masas" como tú dices.

Comment: Hay que mencionar que no es un «uso del subjuntivo con valor del indicativo».  Las terminaciones _-ra_ originalmente solo tenían valor de indicativo y luego adquirieron su sujetividad.  Por eso, es simplemente «un uso del indicativo» y no «un uso del subjuntivo con valor de indicativo»

Michael: nunca lo verás con «fuese» ya que únicamente tiene un valor de subjuntivo.  Yo no veo ninguna razón para censurar el uso de las formas -ra para indicar el pluscuamperfecto, pero bueno, son diferencias de opinión.