# Imperfecto de subjuntivo (sentido indicativo - formas arcaicas)

Tags: subjuntivo

*María había venido a visitar a su amigo poco después de que él estuviera en casa de sus abuelos.*

No entiendo por qué se utiliza el subjuntivo ya que no se trata de una acción hipotética o futura sino todo lo contrario: es una acción que se ha realizado y que tiene un carácter factual

Pregunté a mi profe y él me escibió: 
„las formas en -ARA/-IERA, además de, junto -IERA/-IESE imperfecto de subjuntivo, son también formas arcaicas de PLUSCUAMPERFECTO DE INDICATIVO. Es este caso.“

Ahora no entiendo nada: entonces ¿en el ejemplo de arriba es un caso de subjuntivo o es una forma arcaica del verbo *estar* en el pluscuamperfecto de indicativo?

¡Muchísimas gracias a todos!

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a este sitio. Funcionamos un poco distinto que otros foros, así que por favor saca un poco de tiempo para revisar las secciones de "Tour" y "Help". Para mantener la calidad de las preguntas y el valor de este sitio hay cierto tipo de preguntas que no permitimos. "Alguien sabe algo de XYZ" es muy ambiguo y amplio. Una pregunta más concreta te ayudará a tener mejores respuestas.

Comment: La [Nueva gramática de la lengua española](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi) es un documento de unas 3800 páginas publicado por la RAE sobre, como su nombre lo indica, la gramática española. En la sección 24 -entre otras- trata el tema del subjuntivo, y más concretamente en la 24.2, el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo. // No entiendo a qué te refieres con "equivale al pretérito indefinido...", ¿podrías poner algún ejemplo?

Comment: @Yay seguramente quiso preguntar sobre el *pluscuamperfecto sintético/simple*, como es el caso de «No fui con mis amigos al cine porque ya **viera** (= *había visto*) la película»

Comment: (y también cabe mencionar que no es siempre forma arcaica... para los del noroeste de España, es parte de la lengua cotidiana)

Comment: @guifa Lo encuentro horrible. ¿Está aceptado por la RAE?

Comment: @Ustanak Acéptalo sí, al menos en reconocer que era parte del español medieval y lleva uso continuo en la zona noroccidental de España por influencia gallega y asturiana, y no lo marca como error.  La Gramática ni recomienda ni censura el uso. Podríamos mirar su consejo sobre la enclisis con formas personales (que pervive en esas zonas) para imaginar lo que diría: intención arcaizante o dialectal, sin problema, otros casos, desconsejable (pero no censurado). Pero con el pluscuamperfecto simple, quizás también añadiría situaciones poéticas, literarias, ensayísticas y periodísticas.

Answer (score 2):

Empezaré por el final: lo que tu profesor te dijo tiene un pequeño error (tal vez de copia), pero la idea general es correcta. La forma en -ara/-iera, que actualmente consideramos pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo, originalmente era el pretérito pluscuamperfecto. Pero no así la forma en -ase/-iese, que siempre ha sido el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo. En el portugués actual se mantiene ese aspecto original.

El uso del subjuntivo en la construcción que mencionas se debe a un motivo doble:

- Herencia del antiguo significado pluscuamperfecto de esta forma
- Mímesis con la construcción en presente o futuro

Sobre esto último, pondré un ejemplo. Si intentaras cambiar el tiempo de la frase, tendrías:

> María irá a visitar a su amigo poco después de que él esté (haya estado) en casa de sus abuelos.

Como ves, en este caso necesitas el subjuntivo, pues es una acción que aún no ha sucedido.

Este tipo de uso fue uno de los motivos de que la forma -ara/-iera mutase su significado de pluscuamperfecto al actual imperfecto de subjuntivo.

Tienes una buena explicación sobre esta evolución y los usos del subjuntivo debidos a ella en el [apartado 24.2](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wnfoNYdXkKxHUQV,) de la Nueva Gramática Española de la RAE. Esta evolución explica las ligeras diferencias en el uso de ambas formas del pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo, aunque a veces se ve la forma -ase/-iese en usos que, teóricamente, solo corresponden a la forma -ara/-iera.

Comment: Muchas gracias x la respuesta!!!

Answer (score 1):

El artículo de Wikipedia sobre el [modo subjuntivo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_subjuntivo) da una explicación un tanto más sólida (el énfasis en negrita es de un servidor):

> En gramática tradicional se dice que es el modo de la oración adjunta cuya acción, mediante el contenido de la oración principal o el tipo de nexo con ella, toma el carácter subjetivo de posible, probable, hipotética, creída, deseada, temida o necesaria. Sin embargo, el subjuntivo aparece igualmente marcando hechos que son perfectamente objetivos, reales y constatados (Me alegra que estés aquí), así como el indicativo lo hace en cualquiera de los contextos que la tradición adjudica al modo subjuntivo, como la posibilidad (Posiblemente ya lo sabe), la probabilidad (Probablemente estará durmiendo), la hipótesis (Si llueve, no voy), la creencia (No creo que estén durmiendo), el deseo (Tú te comes eso ahora mismo), el temor (Lo que me da miedo es que tiene una pistola), o la necesidad (Tienes que comerte eso). **El subjuntivo es mejor caracterizado como la suspensión de la modalidad declarativa que expresa el indicativo sobre el hecho que marca, esto es, como el modo de la no-declaración.**

En otros términos, resulta más apropiado entender el subjuntivo como el modo verbal personal que utilizamos en proposiciones subordinadas sustantivas o adverbiales, en la medida en que estén introducidas por una conjunción.

Pero cuidado, el subjuntivo no funciona en proposiciones subordinadas adjetivas o adverbiales de relativo. El arcaísmo al que se refiere tu profesor es al que se refiere [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3213/por-qu%C3%A9-se-usa-el-subjuntivo-en-esta-frase?rq=1), y que cita a [esta página](http://hispanoteca.eu/Gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Imperfecto%20subjuntivo%20literario.htm), que dice, entre otras cosas, lo siguiente:

> En el Libro de Estilo de ABC encontramos lo siguiente: Subjuntivo por indicativo: Evítese el extendido empleo del imperfecto de subjuntivo (cantara) como equivalente del indicativo (había cantado, cantó) en oraciones introducidas por un relativo. Escribir "La sesión, que comenzara a las cuatro de la tarde, se prolongó hasta la madrugada" es un arcaísmo pedante, ajeno al buen uso del castellano moderno. Lo correcto será: "La sesión, que había comenzado...".

La misma fuente cita el "Manual del español urgente":

> Se trata de una pedantería ajena al buen empleo del español moderno (o de un influjo gallego o asturiano). Cantara tuvo ese valor de pluscuamperfecto de indicativo, heredado del latín en la Edad Media, pero lo fue perdiendo, y adquiriendo el de imperfecto de subjuntivo hasta que confundió sus usos con los de cantase. Fueron los poetas románticos quines, para "medievalizar" su estilo, resucitaron el antiguo valor ya olvidado de cantara, y desde entonces se ha mantenido en la literatura. Pero debe estar ausente del lenguaje periodístico, donde ha penetrado por las citadas causas

Finalmente, podríamos destacar que no es el único caso de forma verbal que nominalmente denota un tiempo verbal pero por contexto funciona como un tiempo verbal diferente: el [presente histórico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presente_hist%C3%B3rico) sería el ejemplo clásico.

Comment: muchas gracias!!! : )